# How to call a function when angularjs accordion open only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-accordion, angularjs-bootstrap

Hi I am using angularjs ui bootstrap accordion. Here i want to call when user click on accordion call one function and get user

Here is the code please help me thnks in advance

```js
$scope.load_userdata= function(user_id) {
     console.log(user_id);
    }
```

```html
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
  <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" ng-repeat="user in users">
     <uib-accordion-heading ng-click="load_userdata(user.id)">
       <div class="table">
        <div style="width: 50%">
           @{{user.name}}             
        </div>
        <div>
          Load user data
         </div>
       </div>
       </uib-accordion-heading>
  </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

data and display it

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the problem is. I copied your template in the snippet below and added a simple controller with a working example.

The angular-bootstrap module is not included so you don't get the proper rendering. But it shows you how to define the function in your controller for your template to work.

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
    // dummy users data for the snippet purpose
    $scope.users = [{
            name: 'Joe',
            id: '1', 
            data : 'Married to Jane',
        },
        {
            name: 'John',
            id: '2',
            data : 'Has 3 children',
        },
        {
            name: 'Jack',
            id: '3',
            data : 'Owns a boat',
        },
        {
            name: 'Bob',
            id: '4',
            data : 'Speaks swedish',
        }
    ];

    $scope.load_userdata = function(user_id) {
        console.log("Loading user#%s data", user_id);
        
        // looking for the right user : 
        let user = $scope.users.find(x => x.id === user_id);

        // and toggling the dataLoaded property in the user object
        user.dataLoaded = true;        
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
   <head>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset=utf-8 />
      <title>Angular JS Demo</title>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="ctrl">
      <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
         <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" ng-repeat="user in users">
            <uib-accordion-heading ng-click="load_userdata(user.id)">
               <div class="table">
                  <div style="width: 50%">
                     @{{user.name}}             
                  </div>
                  <div>
                     Load user data
                  </div>
               </div>
            </uib-accordion-heading>
            <div ng-show="user.dataLoaded">
               User's details : 
               {{user.data}}     
            </div>
          </div>
      </uib-accordion>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Surely the `<div ng-show="dataLoaded">` should be inside the accordion, aka a `<div>` inside `<div uib-accordion-group>`

Comment: ehmm, sorry for being annoying, but it's not right now either. The `<div ng-show="dataLoaded">` should be right after this tag `</uib-accordion-heading>` ... I don't think you'd want a user's data displayed in the accordion heading

Comment: @RogerC its what expect thank you,  I think here is one issue if clicks in-side accordion`<div>user data</div>` it functions calls again. But i want only when clicks on header

Comment: @krishnaganisetti It should be fixed now that protozoid pointed it out. I moved the user's data div out of the header.